# Travelling from France with a German student residency and a Fiktionsbescheinigung

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, france, paperwork, residency

I have a 2-year student residency in Germany. The residency ends in a few days so I had an appointment yesterday to renew it. Instead of a new residency I got a Fiktionsbescheinigung where the third box is checked (§ 81 Section 4). I got the Fiktionsbescheinigung  specifically since the reviewer asked if I needed to travel in the next 3 months.

Now I'm travelling next Christmas break and because the closest airport to where I live is in France (Euro airport) that's where I have booked my tickets. I reach the airport via a shuttle bus and my papers don't get checked at the French border so I know I can reach the airport. My question is will I be able to leave and re-enter given that my destination is outside the EU?

Comment: Does the Stack Exchange software support German nouns as tags?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm *Schengen* is a German noun.

Comment: @phoog I was thinking of the word "Fiktionsbescheinigung", which at 22 characters, barely fit the old maximum length requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Timatic, the database used by airlines, states the following when Germany is put as the destination:

> Visa required, **except** for Passengers with a Temporary
>   Residence Permit (Fiktionsbescheinigung) issued by Germany.
>   They must hold the expired resident permit and a valid
>   passport. The third box on the Temporary Residence Permit must
>   be ticked.

When France is put as the destination (and this is where you'll fly to on the way back) this is **not** mentioned.

Unless check-in staff at the departure airport is familiar with the *Fiktionsbescheinigung* and automatically assumes it to be valid for France (I personally have no idea whether it is), they will refer to Timatic, and because this document isn't mentioned when France is put as the destination, they will deny you boarding.

As such, your safest bet is to re-book your return flight so that you fly into a German airport.